# I have two remote branches with similar names. Will this command delete the right one?

Tags: git, git-push, remote-branch

I have two remote branches:

- `origin/dev`
- `origin/origin/dev`

I want to delete `origin/origin/dev`.

Will the following command do what I want?

```
git push origin --delete origin/dev
```

Comment: Many of your questions have no accepted answer. Please review the answers you've got and accept/upvote them as appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2246630/bhartsb?tab=questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do well to pick better branch names; you would avoid a few headaches like this one `:)`

As I understand it, you have two branches living in the remote repo called `origin`:

- `dev`
- `origin/dev`

A quick test in a toy repo indicates that, under the assumption that `origin/HEAD` doesn't point to the remote branch called `origin/dev`, the command

```
git push origin --delete origin/dev
```

will indeed do what you want. To be clear, this command will

- delete the branch called `origin/dev` that lives in the `origin` remote repo, and which is associated with your (local) remote-tracking branch `origin/origin/dev`.
- leave intact the branch called `dev` that lives in the `origin` remote repo, and which is associated with your (local) remote-tracking branch `origin/dev`.

Comment: @bhartsb No problem. When you get a change, though, do take some time to review the answers you got for your other questions.